# Can one apply the Hubbard-Stratonovich transformation to the exponential of the Laplacian?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, statistical-mechanics, many-body

Is there a generalization of the [Hubbard-Stratonovich transformation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hubbard%E2%80%93Stratonovich_transformation) that transforms the exponential of the Laplacian into a Gaussian integral? Or can anyone suggest me how I can find the Hubbard-Stratonovich transformation of second derivative operator, I mean something like $exp(-\frac{a}{2}\frac{d^2}{dz^2})$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the Laplacian

$$ \Delta ~:=~ -\frac{d^2}{dx^2} ~\geq~ 0, $$

the corresponding [HS transformation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hubbard%E2%80%93Stratonovich_transformation) reads

$$\exp\left(-\frac{a}{2}\Delta\right)  f(x)~=~\int_{\mathbb{R}} \!\frac{dy}{\sqrt{2\pi a}}\exp\left(-\frac{y^2}{2a}\right)   f(x+y), \qquad a~>~0.$$

Proof: Use Fourier transformation.